# JFrame pixel precision for canvas

Tags: java, canvas, jframe, pixel

Hey so I'm implementing a Canvas in a JFrame object, however there's a slight annoyance:

If I specify the frame to be a certain dimension, then the title bar is included in the vertical size.  Similarly for the left edge of the window being included with the specified size.  I used absolute positioning to determine the pixel count for the title bar and just made my JFrame that quantity of pixels larger, however I somehow doubt this is platform independent.  Is there a proper way to get/set the quantity of pixels that can appear inside the actually usable contents of a JFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you place your "canvas" (which should not be a `java.awt.Canvas`, but preferably a `javax.swing.JPanel`) into the content pane of the frame. When you assign a preferred size to this component, and afterwards call `pack()` on the frame, then the frame will have the right size to obey the preferred size of the component:

```
canvas = new MyClassExtendingJPanel();
canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(123,456));
frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
...
// At the end:
frame.pack(); 
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: ok, so you suggest that part of the complication is invoked due to the mixture of awt and swing, perhaps? interesting, thanks.  I learnt it this way, for the future I'll try to adapt to learning displaying pixels via only swing somehow

Comment: I did not say this explicitly, but *"Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components"* (as described in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html ) is always a bit problematic. It *should* work in general, but does not always work as expected, and I'd recommend to use Swing components only